# Polygon Soup-Ellipsoid Collision False Positives (Kasper Fauerby)

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I'm trying to implement Kasper Fauerby's collision detection and response in my game but I'm having some issues with the detection part.

Both the vertex and edge collision return false positives, at the moment I'm simply not adding my free-cam's velocity to it's position when a collision is about to occur (Radius of 1 all around).

When my next position will be in the triangle's plane then it looks like the vertex extends a lot further then it should. But this only affects me when I'm moving in the direction of the vertex. I can move parallel to the triangle's normal without colliding with the vertex.

At the moment I stripped down the code all the way to the code that [Kasper provided in his paper](http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf), but here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
bool MeshCollider::CheckTriangleEllipsoid(glm::vec3 p1, glm::vec3 p2, glm::vec3 p3, Ellipsoid *colPackage)
{
    // Make the plane containing this triangle.
    Collision::PLANE trianglePlane(p1, p2, p3);
    // Is triangle front-facing to the velocity vector?
    // We only check front-facing triangles
    // (your choice of course)
    if (trianglePlane.isFrontFacingTo(
    colPackage->normalizedVelocity)) {
    // Get interval of plane intersection:
        double t0, t1;
        bool embeddedInPlane = false;
        // Calculate the signed distance from sphere
        // position to triangle plane
        double signedDistToTrianglePlane = trianglePlane.signedDistanceTo(colPackage->ePosition);
        // cache this as we’re going to use it a few times below:
        float normalDotVelocity = glm::dot(trianglePlane.normal, colPackage->eVelocity);
        // if sphere is travelling parrallel to the plane:
        if (normalDotVelocity == 0.0f) {
            if (fabs(signedDistToTrianglePlane) >= 1.0f) {
            // Sphere is not embedded in plane.
            // No collision possible:
                return false;
            }
            else {
            // sphere is embedded in plane.
            // It intersects in the whole range [0..1]
                embeddedInPlane = true;
                t0 = 0.0;
                t1 = 1.0;
            }
        }
        else {
        // N dot D is not 0. Calculate intersection interval:
            t0 = (-1.0 - signedDistToTrianglePlane) / normalDotVelocity;
            t1 = (1.0 - signedDistToTrianglePlane) / normalDotVelocity;
            // Swap so t0 < t1
            if (t0 > t1) {
                double temp = t1;
                t1 = t0;
                t0 = temp;
            }
            // Check that at least one result is within range:
            if (t0 > 1.0f || t1 < 0.0f) {
                // Both t values are outside values [0,1]
                // No collision possible:
                return false;
            }
            // Clamp to [0,1]
            if (t0 < 0.0) t0 = 0.0;
            if (t1 < 0.0) t1 = 0.0;
            if (t0 > 1.0) t0 = 1.0;
            if (t1 > 1.0) t1 = 1.0;
        }
        // OK, at this point we have two time values t0 and t1
        // between which the swept sphere intersects with the
        // triangle plane. If any collision is to occur it must
        // happen within this interval.
        glm::vec3 collisionPoint;
        bool foundCollison = false;
        float t = 1.0;
        // First we check for the easy case - collision inside
        // the triangle. If this happens it must be at time t0
        // as this is when the sphere rests on the front side
        // of the triangle plane. Note, this can only happen if
        // the sphere is not embedded in the triangle plane.

        if(!embeddedInPlane) {
            glm::vec3 planeIntersectionPoint =
            (colPackage->ePosition - trianglePlane.normal)
            + (float)t0 * colPackage->eVelocity;
            if (checkPointInTriangle(planeIntersectionPoint,
                p1,
                p2,
                p3))
            {
                foundCollison = true;

                t = t0;
                collisionPoint = planeIntersectionPoint;
            }
        }

        // if we haven’t found a collision already we’ll have to
        // sweep sphere against points and edges of the triangle.
        // Note: A collision inside the triangle (the check above)
        // will always happen before a vertex or edge collision!
        // This is why we can skip the swept test if the above
        // gives a collision!


        if (foundCollison == false) {
        // some commonly used terms:
            glm::vec3 velocity = colPackage->eVelocity;
            glm::vec3 base = colPackage->ePosition;

            float velocitySquaredLength = glm::length(velocity);
            float a, b, c; // Params for equation
            float newT;

            // For each vertex or edge a quadratic equation have to
            // be solved. We parameterize this equation as
            // a*t^2 + b*t + c = 0 and below we calculate the
            // parameters a,b and c for each test.
            // Check against points:
            a = velocitySquaredLength;
            // P1
            b = 2.0 * (glm::dot(velocity, base - p1));
            c = glm::length(p1 - base) - 1.0;
            if (getLowestRoot(a, b, c, t, &newT)) {
                t = newT;
                foundCollison = true;
                collisionPoint = p1;
                std::cout << "point 1\n";
            }
            // P2
            b = 2.0 * (glm::dot(velocity, base - p2));
            c = glm::length(p2 - base) - 1.0;
            if (getLowestRoot(a, b, c, t, &newT)) {
                t = newT;
                foundCollison = true;
                collisionPoint = p2;
                std::cout << "point 2\n";
            }

            // P3
            b = 2.0*(glm::dot(velocity, base - p3));
            c = glm::length(p3 - base) - 1.0 ;
            if (getLowestRoot(a, b, c, t, &newT)) {
                t = newT;
                foundCollison = true;
                collisionPoint = p3;
                std::cout << "point 3\n";
            }

            // Check agains edges:
            // p1 -> p2:
            glm::vec3 edge = p2 - p1;
            glm::vec3 baseToVertex = p1 - base;
            float edgeSquaredLength = glm::length(edge);
            float edgeDotVelocity = glm::dot(edge, velocity);
            float edgeDotBaseToVertex = glm::dot(edge, baseToVertex);
            // Calculate parameters for equation
            a = edgeSquaredLength * -velocitySquaredLength +
            edgeDotVelocity*edgeDotVelocity;
            b = edgeSquaredLength*(2*glm::dot(velocity, baseToVertex)) -
            2.0*edgeDotVelocity*edgeDotBaseToVertex;
            c = edgeSquaredLength*(1 - glm::length(baseToVertex)) +
            edgeDotBaseToVertex*edgeDotBaseToVertex;
            // Does the swept sphere collide against infinite edge?
            if(getLowestRoot(a, b, c, t, &newT)) {
            // Check if intersection is within line segment:
                float f = (edgeDotVelocity*newT - edgeDotBaseToVertex) /
                edgeSquaredLength;
                if (f >= 0.0 && f <= 1.0) {
                // intersection took place within segment.
                    t = newT;
                    foundCollison = true;
                    collisionPoint = p1 + f*edge;
                    std::cout << "p1 p2\n";
                }
            }

            // p2 -> p3:
            edge = p3 - p2;
            baseToVertex = p2 - base;
            edgeSquaredLength = glm::length(edge);
            edgeDotVelocity = glm::dot(edge, velocity);
            edgeDotBaseToVertex = glm::dot(edge, baseToVertex);
            // Calculate parameters for equation
            a = edgeSquaredLength * -velocitySquaredLength +
            edgeDotVelocity*edgeDotVelocity;
            b = edgeSquaredLength*(2*glm::dot(velocity, baseToVertex)) -
            2.0*edgeDotVelocity*edgeDotBaseToVertex;
            c = edgeSquaredLength*(1 - glm::length(baseToVertex)) +
            edgeDotBaseToVertex*edgeDotBaseToVertex;
            if (getLowestRoot(a, b, c, t, &newT)) {
                float f = (edgeDotVelocity*newT - edgeDotBaseToVertex) /
                edgeSquaredLength;
                if (f >= 0.0 && f <= 1.0) {
                    t = newT;
                    foundCollison = true;
                    collisionPoint = p2 + f*edge;
                    std::cout << "p2 p3\n";
                }
            }
            // p3 -> p1:
            edge = p1 - p3;
            baseToVertex = p3 - base;
            edgeSquaredLength = glm::length(edge);
            edgeDotVelocity = glm::dot(edge, velocity);
            edgeDotBaseToVertex = glm::dot(edge, baseToVertex);
            // Calculate parameters for equation
            a = edgeSquaredLength * -velocitySquaredLength +
            edgeDotVelocity*edgeDotVelocity;
            b = edgeSquaredLength*(2*glm::dot(velocity, baseToVertex)) -
            2.0*edgeDotVelocity*edgeDotBaseToVertex;
            c = edgeSquaredLength*(1 - glm::length(baseToVertex)) +
            edgeDotBaseToVertex*edgeDotBaseToVertex;
            if (getLowestRoot(a, b, c, t, &newT)) {
                float f = (edgeDotVelocity*newT - edgeDotBaseToVertex) /
                edgeSquaredLength;
                if (f >= 0.0 && f <= 1.0) {
                    t = newT;
                    foundCollison = true;
                    collisionPoint = p3 + f*edge;
                    std::cout << "p3 p1\n";
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundCollison)
            std::cout << t << " t";
        return foundCollison;// Exit here since I'm not using collision response yet.


        // Set result:
        if (foundCollison == true) {
        // distance to collision: ’t’ is time of collision
            float distToCollision = t * colPackage->velocity.length();
            // Does this triangle qualify for the closest hit?
            // it does if it’s the first hit or the closest
            if (colPackage->foundCollision == false ||
            distToCollision < colPackage->nearestDistance) {
            // Collision information nessesary for sliding
                colPackage->nearestDistance = distToCollision;
                colPackage->intersectionPoint = collisionPoint;
                colPackage->foundCollision = true;
            }
        }
    } // if not backface
    return false;
}
```

I'm assuming that the code provided in the paper actually works. People appear to have success with Kasper's paper. Unfortunately not me.

So far what I've tried is:

- Retried implementing it two times now (In case I made an error somewhere).
- Trying out the seperate parts of the collision detection to find what is causing the issue.

Right now I'm just out of ideas, everything appears correct to me but it's still giving me false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

I was using glm::length instead of a function that returns the squaredlength.
This was causing the false positives.